# How to keep Data in the different instance of UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController that i can access to it in to different places in the app, the first one is from the Dashboard and the second is from TabBar. this UIViewController let the user make searches for different Data, but my problem is i would like to keep the last search that the user did and display it wherever the user open the UIViewController. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store the last search in some global object, that can be accessed from either place. I might suggest using a singleton object that manages your last search. This object can be created at app launch, and used to retrieve the last search whenever your UIViewController needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a singleton class, such as:

AppStorage.h

```
@interface AppStorage : NSObject

@property (strong, monatomic) NSString *lastSearch;

+(AppStorage *)sharedAppStorage;

@end
```

AppStorage.m

```
....
@synthesize lastSearch;

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        //load last search from a saved file
    }
}

+(AppStorage *)sharedAppStorage{
    static AppStorage *sharedAppStorage = nil;
    if(!sharedAppStorage){
        sharedAppStorage = [[super allocWithZone:nil]init];
    }
    return sharedAppStorage;
}

....
```

You can then access the saved search from anywhere in the App by using:

```
NSString *savedSearch = [[AppStorage sharedAppStorage] lastSearch];
```

If you want the saved search to persist through app termination, then you should save the search to either NSUserDefaults or use CoreData.  Those are well documented.

Note:  I do not know how you are wanting to save your search, so NSString can be changed to whatever you want in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You should always create a new UIViewController every time the user opens it, and not retain it with a strong reference from a singleton such as the AppDelegate.

Then you can create a singleton instance as TMilligan did in this post and pass it to the every time new UIViewController.

That way is the best of taking care of your memory management.